# How to extend a Python list with an array of PyObjects

Tags: python, performance, python-c-api

I'm trying to deal with an API that returns an array of `PyObject`s and I want to `extend` an existing python `list` with it's contents.

So far I'm just appending every item of the array:

```c
static PyObject *
myfunc(PyObject *module, PyObject *alist, PyObject **items, Py_ssize_t arrsize)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < arrsize; i++) {
        if (PyList_Append(alist, items[i]) == -1) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return alist;
}
```

But a list is more or less just a wrapper around an [array of `PyObject`s](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/listobject.h#L26) itself.

So is there a better (or faster) way to extend that list? I haven't found a function in the Python-C-API and given the overallocation of `PyList_Object` it seems hacky to create a new array, then `memcpy` the original arrays and then just assign it to `((PyList_Object *)alist)->ob_item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intention is implementing or using an `list.extend()`, but

```
l.extend(items)
```

is just equivalent to

```
l[len(l):] = items
```

This can be done within the python c api `PyList_SetSlice` itself, though you'll have the overhead of creating a new list. But it's better than resizing the list with every append.

```
static PyObject *
myfunc(PyObject *module, PyObject *alist, PyObject **items, Py_ssize_t arrsize)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, len = PyList_GET_SIZE(alist);
    PyObject *l = PyList_New(arrsize);
    int r = PyList_SetSlice(alist, len, len + arrsize, l);
    Py_CLEAR(l);
    if (r == -1) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < arrsize; i++) {
        Py_INCREF(items[i]);
        PyList_SET_ITEM(alist, len + i, items[i]);
    }
    return Py_INCREF(alist), alist;
}
```

Additionally you were loosing a reference on return.

Comment: That sounds promising, however `append` may not need to resize the list at all if the "overallocation" left enough room for the to-be-appended items. But at least your approach limits this to a maximum of one resize and one list-creation. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer before accepting, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: You could also reimplement the internal list resize https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L26